# AppDelegate Error

Tags: xcode, swift

I think i posted something about this a while a go and well the problem almost didnt happen anymore
until now when i am trying to create a table view!

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

        {
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.textLabel.text = "Cell number \(indexPath.row)"
            return cell
        }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 11 
    }


}
```

btw -> I am using Xcode 6.1 using swift programming language!

EDIT -> Error is 'Thread1: signal SIGABRT'

thnx,
appswiftgb

ERROR LOG

```
2014-11-12 20:42:40.672 tableViewTutorial[5949:94056] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "vXZ-lx-hvc-view-kh9-bI-dsS" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107377f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108ebbbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107377e6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000107ee5415 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 249
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000107d287f9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000107d5706b -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 44
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000107d575b5 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 216
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000107d576b4 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 92
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000107d58487 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 523
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000107d58f47 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000107e9e509 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107c7c973 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bb7ade8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bb6fa0e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bb6f87e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010badd63e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bade74a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000107c0154d -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 44
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000107c02238 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2642
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000107c00bf2 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010aa482a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072ad53c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072a3285 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072a3045 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072a2486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000107c00669 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    26  UIKit                               0x0000000107c03420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    27  tableViewTutorial                   0x0000000107198f4e top_level_code + 78
    28  tableViewTutorial                   0x0000000107198f8a main + 42
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109695145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: And the error is? How is the code relevant if there's no mention of the app delegate?

Comment: Oh sorry i ment to say the error I am receiving is 'Thread1: signal SIGABRT'

Comment: Where does the error occur, and when? Is there a stack trace? Is this the only vc in your app? You should provide more info, because what provided so far doesn't help much.

Comment: well when i build the app and run it, it seem like the simulator crashes and then directs me to appdelegate showing me the error of  'Thread1: signal SIGABRT'

Comment: read(and post) the error log at the bottom of Xcode when the app crashes also read the error the Compiler is showing. It is most likely not an AppDelegate error do not assume anything until you have all the info.

Comment: here is the error log in the post

Comment: did you use the xcode template to create the class and related xib? Is it possible that you created a class inherited from `UIViewController` first, then changed the superclass to `UITableViewController` directly in the source file?

Comment: yeh thats what i did i used single view application. Then changed it from uiviewcontroller to uitableviewcontroller. Is there a way to get round this and still be able to use uitableviewcontroller

Comment: may be cause your cell return nil value!

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing numberOfSections for your table view delegate, it may be crashing because that is missing.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is dragging a Table View Controller from object library using IB and then set the Class attribute to your `UITableViewController` subclass.

If you just change the **Class** to a `UITableViewController` subclass for a regular View Controller in IB, it will not create the tableview for you.